# Django FileField url not relative

Tags: django, file, django-models

I have something like:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/httpd/foo/media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'http://www.example.org/media/'
```

(...)

```
file = models.FileField(upload_to='test')
```

When I create an object with that field in the admin page Django stores in the DB the full file path, like: "/home/httpd/foo/media/test/myfile.pdf". This is contrary to what says in the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField).

> All that will be stored in your
>   database is a path to the file
>   (relative to MEDIA_ROOT).

When I use the file.url in a template I get something like:

> http://www.example.org/home/httpd/foo/media/test/myfile.pdf

instead of what I would like:

> http://www.example.org/media/test/myfile.pdf

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using just the default admin with no customization?  As in, there is no code you've written that interferes with how that field is getting saved?

Comment: (The admin had an unrelated M2M customization of another model member)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just did a sample FileField in one of my projects and it seemed to work as you are expecting.  Here are a couple things to try.

Try making your settings like the following.  I know they say it is bad to not end your MEDIA_URL with a / but this is how I do it and I like it better.  You just have to remember whenever you use MEDIA_URL in a template to follow it with a slash: href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/path/to/file"

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/httpd/foo/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media'
```

If that doesn't help anything, create a new simplified model with a FileField nothing customized and see if you are still getting the same problem.

Comment: You are right, it was working the way you said it. I suspect that what happened was that the web server was still using the old python files. I transitioned to the production server recently so I sometimes still forget to 'touch' the configuration file, to apply the changes.

Comment: As of Django 1.9 it is impossible to not end media_url with a slash : ImproperlyConfigured "If set, MEDIA_URL must end with a slash"