# Django: generate download link

Tags: django, download

I have a `File` model, which store `path` field - path in the filesystem to file. All files are stored in MEDIA_ROOT/files

In template I want generate download link for `File` object. What is the best way to do this? Should I use static file handling in django?

TIA!

**UPD**

`File` model

```
class File(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to = os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT,'items'))
    format = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
```

In item's View I do the following:

`files = File.objects.filter(item_id = id)`

and the pass `files` to the template

in template I use `files.1.file.url` for example and still have bad url like `site.com/home/dizpers/...`

**UPD2**

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756190/django-filefield-url-not-relative)

**Solution**

My problem was in File model, in `file` field. In upload_to parameter I use absolute path, but must use relative path:

`file = models.FileField(upload_to = 'items')`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you mean by "generate download link", but to simply link to the file, just use `{{ some_file.url }}` as your `href`.

Comment: And it will work for my custom File object? Not django's File object.

Comment: I tried it. Doesn't work. still get urls like site.com/home/dizpers/data/......./file.pdf where `home/dizpers/...` is path to the file on the disk

Comment: I was assuming that your `File` model still utilized a true-blue `FileField` instead of just a standard `CharField`. There's really no reason not to, as both are stored the same way in the database; `FileField` just has an API attached for dealing with I/O. Nevertheless, if you just need a very basic link you can use `{{ MEDIA_URL }}files/{{ file_instance.path }}`.

Comment: Oh, if you're storing the full absolute path, then, yeah, you're going to have problems. You'll need to strip out the `MEDIA_ROOT` part of the path first (via some method on your model most likely) and then attach `MEDIA_URL`.

Comment: The most interesting moment here - that I use FileField - see updated question.

Comment: Solved. Answer in question text:)

Answer (score 6):

In `models.py`:

```
import os

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models

class File(models.Model):
    ... (your existing File model)

    @property
    def relative_path(self):
        return os.path.relpath(self.path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

(using [the `relpath` method](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) to strip `MEDIA_ROOT` from the value of `self.path`)

In your `file_detail.html` (or equivalent) template:

```
<a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.relative_path }}'>{{ file.name }}</a>
```

*NB* as Chris says, it's better to use a `FileField` here. The above will hopefully work for your exact situation, but unless you're deeply committed to arranging things that way, I'd suggest changing to the dedicated field.

Answer (score 5):

try using `href="{{ STATIC_URL }}/files/somefile"`, or `href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}/files/somefile"` for user uploaded content