# Download local file link in html django template

Tags: python, html, django, download

Basically I have a django template from which I show data about a document and I want a link to download the file. I tried something like this but it is not working:

```
<div class="metadata-container">
        <div class="metadata-title">
            <div>Version</div>
            <div>Author</div>
            <div>File</div>
        </div>
        <div class="metadata-content">
            <div>{{ document.version }}</div>
            <div>{{ document.author }}</div>
            <a href=document.file download><div>{{ document.file }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The filename in format '/documents/2017/filename.txt' is in document.file variable or however it's called. How can I use it in the  ? or how can I make it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django download a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write a method inside your Document model a method which should return the correct link to the file.

Similar to:

```
  def get_document_url(self):
    if self.file:
      return '/documents/2017/ + self.file.name + ".txt"
```

And then inside html you can get it with:

```
<a href={{document.get_document_url}}>Link</a>
```

Comment: and then what? cause inside the html, how would I call that?

Comment: that downloads without having the downlaod tag in a?\

Comment: get_document_url returns exactly my document.file and document.file inside the {{ }} in href doesn't work

Comment: is your path to the file correct? did you check it in browser?

Comment: Instead of http://localhost:8000/media/documents/20170108/eula.3082.txt it is taking me to http://localhost:8000/documents/documents/20170108/eula.3082.txt so something is not working properly

Comment: @Mocktheduck ok! can you show your model? What is inside upload_to? Also you can check this question. I think it is related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871104/django-generate-download-link