# django download file not found

Tags: python, django, download

I'm using Python 3.6 and django 2.2 to develop a webserver. I want to have a webpage displaying a download link for a file I generated based on user input.

In my setting.py I have:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join.(BASE_DIR,'media')
MEDIA_URL='/media/'
```

In my views.py I have

```
query.outputfile.name = os.path.join('submission',query_id,'output_file.txt')
```

to associate the filefield object to the file that I created:

```
path/to/project/media/submission/[query_id]/output_file.txt
```

And when I include

```
print(query.outputfile.url)
```

I got:

```
media/submission/[query_id]/output_file.txt
```

In my html template I have

```
<a href={{ query.outputfile.url }} download> Download output file here </a>
```

On the webpage the file link points to

```
[local ip]/media/submission/[query_id]/output_file.txt
```

But when I click on the link chrome says "Failed - No file" and on the cmd line I got

```
Not Found: /media/submission/[query_id]/output_file.txt
```

I found related questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871104/django-generate-download-link) but do not understand what's wrong with my code.

My questions are:

1. The .url seems to be relative to my MEDIA_ROOT, but why it cannot find my file? Does the cmd line error point to the absolute path /media/... ? I tried to make that path and file but still got the same error.
2. What should I do to generate the download link?

Thanks

Comment: Success in serving static files is going to be entirely dependent on your server configuration.  Meaning, it's fine that your link target is rendering a URL but now your server needs to be configured to serve files from that directory.  Did you check the Django docs for static file configuration?  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/. If so, then you'll want to post the relevant configuration settings with your question, to make sure that they are correct.

Comment: @TylerGannon Hi, thanks for the comment, adding static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in the url indeed fixed my problem. Another solution I got was to add a url pattern for the files and a FileResponse function in the view but that's less elegent. Thanks again! I'm happy to choose your comment as the accepted answer if that's a thing.