# How to get a download option of dynamic table in Angular using Django Database ( each time we will have different tables in Database)

Tags: python, django, angular, database, api

I have tables in Django Data Base with name TBL_Result_1_1, TBL_Result_1_2 etc.

[Image of All tables in Django Backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uq6QJ.png)

I am creating a dashboard in angular frontend, our model will generate tables in Django database with different tables name, each time we run the model . I want to get all tables in dashboard with a download option so a user can download all these tables with click of button. Problem is these tables are not static we will have different number of tables each time and different number of parameters. I know how to get a static table in frontend but not sure with dynamic table with dynamic parameters. Their has to be specific way to this solution.

Problem i don't want to add model in model.py each time

I have used models.py for static tables in django, but these tables are dynamic. Will not able to add models.py each time for each table.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am creating a dashboard in angular frontend, our model will generate tables in Django database with different tables name, each time we run the model . I want to get all tables in dashboard with a download option so a user can download all these tables with click of button. Problem is these tables are not static we will have different number of tables each time and different number of parameters. I know how to get a static table in frontend but not sure with dynamic table with dynamic parameters. Their has to be specific way to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a function in your views.py to get the table dynamically. After that give this table name to a URL that you created before for the download link. This function will run the download URL.

[visit here to see download url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11872619/15071244)

If you would ask your question more specific stack overflow could help you more.